# Difference between $this->db->replace() $this->db->update()

Tags: codeigniter

I don't get the difference between query builder's Replace and Update. Especially the documentation for Replace...

> This method executes a REPLACE statement, which is basically the SQL standard for (optional) DELETE + INSERT, **using PRIMARY and UNIQUE keys as the determining factor.**

...but I see no indication of using a PK in the example. Am I missing some fundamental knowledge here? (I understand Update just fine).

Replace

```
$data = array(
    'title' => 'My title',
    'name'  => 'My Name',
    'date'  => 'My date'
);

$this->db->replace('table', $data);
```

Update

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'name' => $name,
    'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer  this link ...........https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**REPLACE**

It's like insert. but if the primary key being inserted is the same one as another one, the old one will be deleted and the new one will be inserted.

**UPDATE**

Updates the current row that you tried to update.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I was wondering though, is it the whole row that is deleted and replaced, or just the properties specified to be replaced.

Comment: It is the whole role that is deleted and replaced. @user3442612 , if my answer is correct for you, kindly give me a check mark :)